# How does Rails render take options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I'm going thru the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and stuck with the below example:

[image]

What is the `search: @q` part about? I can see it as a hash option that is passed to the partial, but how is that used? The partial uses `@q` but what does that have to do with the key `search`? And the `yield f`? Does that just put the markup `<p>
    Title contains: <%= f.text_field :title_contains %>
  </p>` onto the screen?

Comment: pretty sure the `search: @q` is an unused parameter, and it does seem the block html gets passed to yield

Comment: how does it work with there being a f block in both the view and the partial? in order for f to be passed to yield doesn't it have to be in a content_for tag?

Answer (score 1):

In both example `search: @q` is passed as locals into the partial. Which is eventually not getting used anywhere in 'search_filters' partial.

For more details see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render

Specially this line.

> If no options hash is passed or :update specified, the default is to
>   render a partial and use the second parameter as the locals hash.